# Is there a standard way in Java for obtaining the numeric reference value of an object?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to output the value of a reference. This should be similar to printing the value of a pointer in languages like C or GoLang.

I understand that the reference value is not an address, as objects in Java get shuffled in memory during garbage collection. However, the JVM must be able to distinguish all object instances, via their reference value. This reference value is not necessarily an integral type but I want to explore its data within Java.

To be clear, I want the *reference value*, the thing that is compared when the `==` operator is used between objects in Java.

How can I go about obtaining this value using Java? Something like System.referenceValue(Object)? Are the reference values themselves also ephemeral, and thus out of the question?

Comment: Some garbage collectors just rewrite any reference to an object that has been moved around.

Comment: What is even worse: Some other garbage collectors may only do the rewrite on the first read of the reference.

Comment: The Java Debug Interface allows a debugger to get unique ids for objects, but a normal Java program can't get anything like this.

Comment: Unless you put every object you encounter into a `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: I figured all of this could be the case. I'm experimenting with a Go runtime in Java, and I needed a substitute for its uintptr. I figure a WeakReference will have to do.